# When using git log --graph my commit missing on different branch

Tags: git

My commit history should look like this:

[image]

When I checkout `master` I get this as my commit history:

[image]

Notice I am in the `master` branch and not the `heading-update` branch which I should be in. If I check out the `heading-update` branch and run git `log --oneline --graph` I get the following output:

[image]

Now I'm in the right branch but I am missing the last commit `c26ae66` on master like in the top picture. I am very confused as to why this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git log` works by starting from the commit(s) you tell it to start from, and working backwards.

The commit at the tip of `master` is `c26ae66`.  Its parent—its immediate predecessor commit, one step back in history—is `c774c8c`.  This is a merge commit, so it has two immediate parents: `7e344d8` as its first parent, and `7856b65` as its second.  (`git log --graph` draws the second parent in the down-and-right direction, with the first parent drawn down-but-straight, so that you can tell them apart.  Other graph drawing programs may or may not do this.)  Each of these two commits has one parent, and so on.

Note that `7e344d8` is also on branch `footer`—in fact, it's the *tip* commit of `footer`—and `7856b65` is also on, and is the tip commit of, branch `sidebar`.  Meanwhile `c774c8c` is also on branch `heading-update` and is the tip of that branch.  So the last commit shown here, `73b229f Initial commit`, is on *all* of these branches.  It's normal in Git for commits to be on more than one branch like this.

When you `git checkout master` and run `git log` without telling it which commit to start from, it starts from `c26ae66`—the commit identified by the name `master`—as it traverses the graph, one commit at a time, moving backwards from child to parent(s).  This gets tricky at the merge, since it has to visit *both* legs of the merge, but that's what it does.  That shows `c26ae66` first, then `c774c8c`.  (Then the two parents are shown in some order: exactly what order, well, that's another tricky bit...)

When you `git checkout heading-update` and run `git log` without telling it which commit to start from, it starts from commit `c774c8c`: the commit identified by `heading-update`.  It then moves backwards from child to parent(s), one commit at a time.  This never visits commit `c26ae66` as that requires going *forwards*, and Git's internal arrows all point *backwards*.

So this is all quite normal.  If you'd like `git log` to start from some other commit(s), name them on the command line:

```
git log [options] master heading-update footer sidebar
```

for instance, or:

```
git log [options] --branches
```

or:

```
git log [options] --all
```

The `--branches` and `--all` options mean *all branches* and *all refs* respectively.  *Refs* or *references* is the general term that encompasses branch names like `master`—really, `refs/heads/master`—and tag names like `v1.2` which is really `refs/tags/v1.2`, and many other kinds of names.

(The `--branches` option can take a glob-style pattern, such as `--branches="feature/*"`.  You may or may not need to quote the `*` against your command line interpreter, depending on which shell you use and various shell configuration options you set if that shell has configuration options.)